# Inserting a row into a JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

EDIT: Problem Solved. I had accidentally put a `return` inside of the `if` statement instead of `break`. The function was exiting before altering the `DefaultTableModel`.

`StockNameArr` is an array of all stock symbols in the table (which are alphabetically arranged), arranged itself in alphabetical order.

This class represents a `JTable` with two clickable columns. The first column only prints to `stdout` right now, and that works fine. The second one deletes the row it is in and arranges the name of each stock in alphabetical order in a `JComboBox`. This also works correctly as far as I can tell.

When one of the items in the `JComboBox` is clicked, it should delete the item, create a `String[8]` (matching the other columns of 8 rows), insert the stock name from the item that was clicked, and insert the array as a row at the same place it was previously deleted from.

What actually happens, though, is that the item is deleted from the `JComboBox`, while the new row is never inserted into the table. I've tried calling:

```
model.insertItemAt(...);
thisTable.setModel(model);
```

But it didn't do anything. Thinking that maybe `model` or `thisTable` were't set up correctly, I referenced `thisTable` to this as a class variable, and tried to insert a row into the `TableModel` withouth even creating a new variable for it in the inner class. Still, no luck.

Can anyone help me?

```
import java.awt.event.Action/Event;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class JMainTable extends JTable { 
    JMainTable thisTable = this; //Represents this class in inner classes
    final String[] stockNames;
    DefaultTableModel model;
    JComboBox<String> dropdown;
    ArrayList<String> dropdownStocks = new ArrayList<String> ();
    int rowChangeOffset = 0;
    public JMainTable(DefaultTableModel tableModel, String[] stockNameArr, JComboBox<String> combobox) {
        super(tableModel);
//      thisTable = this;
        stockNames = stockNameArr;
        addMouseListener(new mainTableListener());
        model = tableModel;

        dropdown = combobox;
        dropdown.putClientProperty("JComboBox.isTableCellEditor", Boolean.TRUE); 
        //^ prevents ActionListener from firing when scrolling through list with arrow keys 

            dropdown.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if (!e.getActionCommand().equals(ActionEvent.KEY_EVENT_MASK)){
                       System.out.println("Clicked");
                       JComboBox<String> source = (JComboBox<String>) e.getSource();
                      String stockString = (String) source.getSelectedItem();
                      int index = dropdownStocks.indexOf(stockString);
                      try {
                          source.removeItemAt(index);
                          dropdownStocks.remove(index);
                      } catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException arrEx) {}
                      int indexInStockNames = 0; //for compiler
                      for(int i = 0; i<stockNames.length; i++) {
                          if(stockNames[i].equals(stockString)) {
                              indexInStockNames = i;
                              return;
                          }//end of If
                      }//End of For
                     String[] replacementRow = new String[8];
                     replacementRow[0] = stockString;
                     //model.insertRow(indexInStockNames, replaceRow);
                     ((DefaultTableModel) thisTable.getModel()).insertRow(indexInStockNames, replacementRow);
                     if(index>=0) {//Prevents offset from being changed 
                                   //when user clicks on empty JComboBox
                         rowChangeOffset--;
                     }

                    }
                }
            });
    }

    class mainTableListener extends MouseAdapter {
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent mouseevent) {
            int column;
            if((column = thisTable.getSelectedColumn()) == 6) {
                int row = thisTable.getSelectedRow();
                System.out.println("Button for " + stockNames[row + rowChangeOffset] + " working.");//TESTING
                //NOIMPLEMEN
            } else if((column = thisTable.getSelectedColumn()) == 7) {
                int row = thisTable.getSelectedRow();
                model.removeRow(row);
                try{
                dropdownStocks.add(stockNames[row + rowChangeOffset]);
                } catch(Exception adsf) {adsf.printStackTrace(); System.out.println(stockNames[row+rowChangeOffset]);}
                int index;
                try {
                    Collections.sort(dropdownStocks);
                    index = dropdownStocks.indexOf(stockNames[row+rowChangeOffset]);
                } catch(Exception ex) {/*dropdownStocks may be empty*/
                    index=0;
                }

                dropdown.insertItemAt(stockNames[row+rowChangeOffset], index);
                rowChangeOffset = rowChangeOffset + 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You've not posted a viable [mcve] yet, code that is short, that compiles and runs for us unaltered, and that demonstrates your problem, and that poses a problem for our ability to understand your problem and your code and thus help you. Consider putting in the effort to create one of these beasts, and then posting it here as code-formatted text with your question (not in a link).

Comment: Note that this is *never* code: `catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException arrEx) {}`, it is code that should never be in your program. Why do you feel the need to include it? Also, and again, please improve your program if you still need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, it will help to add a row to your model that is linked to your table

```
 model.addRow(new Object[]{objec1,object2}); //param to count of columns to table
 jTable1.setModel(modelo);
/*You are not required if in the beginning did something like this
modelo = (DefaultTableModel)jTable1.getModel();*/
```

Comment: Please explain a bit why you think that your answer will help the OP (original poster) and how it improves on his current posted code.

Comment: Accepted because it would have worked had I entered the code correctly.